# Minecraft Server Ping Protocol C#

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcp, minecraft

I've been working a while on emulating a Minecraft server in C# and I can't manage to send a response back to the client for the server query protocol listed here:

[Server List Ping](http://wiki.vg/Server_List_Ping)

So here's my code for it, the problem is that the client doesn't seem to be receiving the response sent by the "server":

```
            TcpListener tcpl;
            TcpClient tcpc;

            //tcp for server ping
            tcpl = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), QUERY_PORT);
            tcpl.Start();
            tcpl.BeginAcceptSocket(new AsyncCallback(tcp_recv), null);

            tcpc = tcpl.AcceptTcpClient();
            tcpc.SendBufferSize = 1024;
            NetworkStream ns = tcpc.GetStream();

            //inside tcp_recv
            else if (buffer_one[0] == 0xFE && buffer_one[1] == 0x01) //status ping protocol version 4
            {
                invoke_console("Handling Status Ping Protocol Version 4");

                byte[] data = { 0xFF }; //kick message
                byte[] data_len = { 0x00, 0x23 };
                misc.concat_byte_array(ref data, data_len);
                misc.concat_byte_array(ref data, new byte[] { 0x00, 0xa7, 0x00, 0x31, 0x00, 0x00 }); //maningless chars
                misc.concat_byte_array(ref data, Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes("47"));
                misc.concat_byte_array(ref data, new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00 });
                misc.concat_byte_array(ref data, Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes("1.4.2"));
                misc.concat_byte_array(ref data, new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00 });
                misc.concat_byte_array(ref data, Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes("A Minecraft Server"));
                misc.concat_byte_array(ref data, new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00 });
                misc.concat_byte_array(ref data, Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes("0"));
                misc.concat_byte_array(ref data, new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00 });
                misc.concat_byte_array(ref data, Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes("20"));

                //File.WriteAllBytes("sending.txt", data);

                //invoke_console(String.Format("Total number of bytes: {0}", data.Length));
                //invoke_console(String.Format("Sent {0} bytes...", s.Send(data))); //send protocol 4 data
                ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
```

This is async and I didn't paste the function that I used for the AsyncCallback because it had a lot of meaningless debug code and test code for the 1.7 ping protocol but everything seems to be using the 1.6 protocol so I'm working on that mainly now.

If you have any questions feel free to ask because I know this isn't super specific on the problem being encountered.

Comment: Seems like you are accepting two clients.

Comment: One is a listener and the other is a client that I use to communicate with the endpoint, my other alternative is using AcceptSocket and using a socket to communicate which I could do with tcpc.Client.

Comment: I think you misunderstand how this works. TcpListener encapsulates a listening socket. For each accepted connection you get another socket. You accept two times using different methods.

Comment: How would you do it then?

Comment: You accept in a loop forever. Each accepted socket/client is processed independently, for example on a new thread.

Comment: That's what I did already, I shortened the code that I put in the op from my original.

Comment: I don't know how to continue to help you. From the code posted I can clearly tell that you are accepting sockets in two places which is a mistake. Did you understand what I said about that? Follow up on it.

Comment: Where is the second place?

Comment: BeginAcceptSocket and AcceptTcpClient. Both accept a fresh client except that the latter packages in `new TcpClient(mySocket)`.

Comment: So should I just use AcceptSocket() on the listener or is there a way to eliminate the socket being used by the listener?

Comment: It doesn't matter **as long as you serve every socket that you have accepted**. If you like the TcpClient class, go with AcceptClient. AcceptSocket is fine, too. If you accept a client and just throw it away, the client will not be serviced. Makes sense?

Comment: Yes it does, I just read over the documentation again for TcpListener.BeginAcceptSocket and it seems that it's best to grab the socket from TcpListener.EndAcceptSocket

Comment: If you want to use async IO for accept that's the way to do it. But likely, you should just use the synchronous version because it is easier to use. How many clients do you expect? If its just a few dozen the completely synchronous socket IO API is a much easier choice at no disadvantage.

Comment: I only expect one every once in a while, maybe two at the same time at best.